# Magento custom module - unable to call block method from template

Tags: magento, templates

I'm working on a custom module to display CMS content. I have a custom front controller which is working as expected. I'm able to call various front actions from the controller. I am using an existing template, which is also displaying as it should. I'm also loading a layout update xml file, from which I was able to remove the product menu, which I don't need, and add a reference block for my custom block's template file.

I know the correct template override file is loading, as I'm testing with the following:

```
<?php echo __FILE__ . " loaded <br>"; ?>
```

Which is echoing the correct filename.

However, when I call my custom block method from that same template file, I get nothing.

My module namespace/module is Cmpreshn/Projects. Following is what I have so far:

Config file in
app/code/local/Cmpreshn/Projects/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cmpreshn_Projects>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cmpreshn_Projects>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <projects>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cmpreshn_Projects</module>
                    <frontName>education</frontName>
                </args>
            </projects>
        </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <projects>
                <file>projects.xml</file>
            </projects>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <projects>
                <class>Projects_Block_List</class>
            </projects> 
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Front controller in
app/code/local/Cmpreshn/Projects/controllers/ProjectsController.php

```
<?php

    class Cmpreshn_Projects_ProjectsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

        public function indexAction(){
            $this->listAction();
        }

        public function listAction(){

            echo "list action called<br>";

            /* get request and save params to object */
            $this->request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

            /* layout overrides for this module in app/design/frontend/default/pmc1/layout/projects.xml */
            $this->loadLayout();

            /* use the education template */
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock("root")->setTemplate("page/pmc_education.phtml");

            /* render the layout */
            $this->renderLayout();

        }

    }
```

XML updates in
app/design/frontend/default/pmc1/layout/projects.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <projects_projects_list>
        <remove name="top.menu"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html" name="page" template="cmpreshn/projects/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </projects_projects_list>
</layout>
```

Template overrides and call to custom block in
app/design/frontend/default/pmc1/template/cmpreshn/project/list.phtml

```
<?php echo __FILE__ . " loaded <br>"; ?>
<?php echo $this->getProjectsList(); ?>
```

Last but not least, my custom block class in
app/code/local/Cmpreshn/Proejcts/Block/List.php

```
<?php

    class Cmpreshn_Projects_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

        public function _construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            echo "projects list block constructor called<br>";
        } // end constructor

        public function getProjectsList() {
            echo "getProjectsList called <br>";
            return("getProjectsList called");
        }

    } // end class
```

As I mentioned previously, I am getting the output from the first line of my list.phtml template file, but no output from my custom block method, and no indication that my block is loading (no output from block _construct() method either )

Any help is appreciated. I'm ready to pull my eyes out over this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the block type to `projects/list` in your projects.XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
   <projects_projects_list> 
      <remove name="top.menu"/> 
      <reference name="content"> 
         <block type="projects/list" name="page" template="cmpreshn/projects/list.phtml/>
      </reference> 
   </projects_projects_list> 
</layout>
```

you may get the output now.

Comment: That's actually worse. The block is still not loading, and now I also don't see the test output from my list.phtml template file. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @cmpreshn i think you may get answer from the Mr_Green

Comment: The class registration tag in the config file works fine as-is (Cmpreshn_Projects_BLock). You and Mr. Green were right about the block type in my layout file - it needs to be projects/list. Additionally, the constructor function in my block class was causing a problem. I first replaced my entire block function with just die('block loaded'); -- that confirmed that the block type needed to be projects/list in order to load the class. I then tried taking out the constructor function entirely (with call to parent::__construct) -- and it works! I'll post the corrected code above.

Comment: Working code for class block: `code`
<?php
   class Cmpreshn_Projects_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getProjectsList() {
        return "getProjectsList called<br>";
    }
} // end `code`

Working code for the layout xml:
`code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <projects_projects_list>
        <remove name="top.menu"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="projects/list" name="page" template="cmpreshn/projects/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </projects_projects_list>
</layout> `code`

Answer (score 2):

I just observed your code and found the following errors:

- Registeration of block in registering module file (config.xml) **seems** wrong.

  ```
  <global>
      <blocks>
          <projects>
              <class>Cmpreshn_Projects_Block</class>  <!-- Not Projects_Block_List -->
          </projects> 
      </blocks> 
  </global>
  ```
- The `type` attribute is wrong in Block element of layout file (projects.xml). You should not call `page/html` instead you should call `projects/list`.

There might be more typos. but I could found the above two only. I hope this solves your problem.